# Why do I get a "conflicting type" warning when I implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: objective-c, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm implementing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method in a tableviecontroller implementation.  I get a "conflicting type" warning in my code.  Everything seems to work, but the warning bugs me.  The code in my implementation file is as follows.

```
- (void *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
```

Originally I had a return type of (NSIndexPath *), but found the type should be void as stated in UITableView.h.  Both return types have the same effect.  The code works, but I get the following warning...

```
warning: conflicting types for '-(void)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView...
```

Thank you for any help you can give...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your return type should be `void`, not `void *`, as stated in the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) documentation.

Comment: This man is correct.  Also, when writing SDK delegate methods like those in table view handling I find it's always best to open the documentation and directly copy the declaration from there so they don't get messed up.